# Finding minimum by groups and among columns

Tags: r, min

I am trying to find the minimum value among different columns and group.
A small sample of my data looks something like this:

```
     group cut group_score_1 group_score_2
1        a   1             3           5.0
2        b   2             2           4.0
3        a   0             2           2.5
4        b   3             5           4.0
5        a   2             3           6.0
6        b   1             5           1.0
```

I want to group by the groups and for each group, find the row which contains the minimum group score among both group scores and then also get the name of the column which contains the minimum (group_score_1 or group_score_2),
so basically my result should be something like this:

```
      group cut group_score_1 group_score_2
1        a   0             2           2.5
2        b   1             5           1.0
```

I tried a few ideas, and came up eventually to dividing the into several new data frames, filtering by group and selecting the relevant columns and then using `which.min()`, but I'm sure there's a much more efficient way to do it. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I want to iterated over rows and columns and find the row with the minimum group_score. Then just keep the row with the minimum and tell me which group score it is.

Comment: The row that has lowest next group score, meaning if two rows have the same lowest group score, then the cut between them would be the row that it's next lowest group score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[which.min(do.call(pmin, .SD))], 
     group, .SDcols = patterns('^group_score')]$V1]
#   group cut group_score_1 group_score_2
#1:     a   0             2           2.5
#2:     b   1             5           1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun
Since my data includes columns which are not to be calculated (logicals) , is there a data.table solution which keeps those columns?

Answer (score 1):

For each `group`, you can calculate `min` value and select the row in which that value exist in one of the column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter({tmp = min(group_score_1, group_score_2);
          group_score_1 == tmp | group_score_2 == tmp})

#  group   cut group_score_1 group_score_2
#  <chr> <int>         <int>         <dbl>
#1 a         0             2           2.5
#2 b         1             5           1
```

---

The above works well when you have only two `group_score` columns. If you have many such columns it is not possible to list down each one of them with `group_score_1 == tmp | group_score_2 == tmp` etc. In such case, get the data in long format and get the corresponding `cut` value of the minimum value and join the data. Assuming `cut` is unique in each group.

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('group_score')) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(cut = cut[which.min(value)]) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c("group", "cut"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `pmin` + `ave` + `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  as.logical(ave(
    do.call(pmin, df[grep("group_score_\\d+", names(df))]),
    group,
    FUN = function(x) x == min(x)
  ))
)
```

which gives

```
  group cut group_score_1 group_score_2
3     a   0             2           2.5
6     b   1             5           1.0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(group = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), cut = c(1L, 
2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L), group_score_1 = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L
), group_score_2 = c(5, 4, 2.5, 4, 6, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```